# Date compression SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this function and the query

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[dateholiday]
(@date1 AS DATETIME,
@date2 AS DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Answer AS DATETIME

IF(@date1 = @date2)
SET @Answer = @date2

RETURN @Answer
END
```

the Query:

```
    SELECT Posted_By
    ,Document_Number
    ,Account_Description
    ,dbo.dateholiday(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feiertage, 104), 20), [dbo].[QLIK].[Posted_Date]) AS Holiday
FROM [dbo].[FEIERTAGE_O]
    ,[dbo].[QLIK]
WHERE dbo.dateholiday(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feiertage, 104), 20), [dbo].[QLIK].[Posted_Date]) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dbo.dateholiday(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feiertage, 104), 20), [dbo].[QLIK].[Posted_Date])
    ,Posted_By
    ,Document_Number
    ,Account_Description
```

where FEIERTAGE_O is a list of 115 dates but the Posted_Date is about 1914495. The query works fine but the only problem is that it takes  a lot and a lot of time. So I need to make it faster .

Any ideas !

Comment: Please post your actual execution plan of your query

Comment: `Join without predicate`, `Scalar function`, `Index Scan` - primary problems

Comment: is that the whole function? Seems weird, also the name doesn't seem to fit the function. Anyway, your function expects two `datetime` values, yet you feed it (at least) one `NVARCHAR`. I assume it's implicitly convert to a `datetime`. It may also help to use the function in a subquery, so you don't have to evaluate it so often. The function is executed for the `select`, for the `where` and for the `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this helps:

```
SELECT      Posted_By
,           Document_Number
,           Account_Description
,           Holiday
FROM        (
                SELECT  DISTINCT    Posted_By
                ,           Document_Number
                ,           Account_Description
                ,           dbo.dateholiday(CONVERT(DATETIME, Feiertage, 104)), [dbo].[QLIK].[Posted_Date]) AS Holiday
                FROM        [dbo].[FEIERTAGE_O]
                CROSS JOIN  [dbo].[QLIK] 
            ) A
WHERE       Holiday IS NOT NULL
```

Notice the `cross join`, you didn't specify an `on` clause for your implicit `join` (you should always use explicit `join` syntax), are you sure a cartesian product is what you need? This will explode the number of records (according to google calculator to infinity). Is that why you did a `group by` (even though you're not aggregating)? I've replaced the `group by` with a `distinct`, will give the same result, but is clearer. Have a look at your `join` whether it is really correct.

**Edit**

After re-reading your question I think this will give you what you need:

```
SELECT      Posted_By
,           Document_Number
,           Account_Description
,           Holiday
FROM        (
                SELECT  DISTINCT    Posted_By
                ,           Document_Number
                ,           Account_Description
                ,           dbo.dateholiday(CONVERT(DATETIME, Feiertage, 104)), [dbo].[QLIK].[Posted_Date]) AS Holiday
                FROM        [dbo].[FEIERTAGE_O] FO
                LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[QLIK] Q
                        ON  Q.[Posted_Date] = FO.Feiertage
            ) A
WHERE       Holiday IS NOT NULL
```

If that's the case, you don't really need the function any more. You can instead use a `CASE` expression.